# Employer ask me to work at a different location with very little notice (less than 30 days)

Tags: employment, employer

My employer just release a news that company will move to another state (30 miles away) and the move date is Mid-February. The employer doesn't plan to have any compensation for employee's commute cost, gas, or salary. Is this reasonable? Is there something we can do as employee? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What state are you in (currently)? If pressed, I would assume NJ based on the name, but better not to assume.

Answer (score 7):

Unless your contract, whether individual or collective, has a clause requiring this compensation you are out of luck. Sometimes one of the “benefits”  for a company’s move is to leave behind workers who are not 100% committed to the company in that they would not move or commute a long way to keep their job. 30 miles isn’t very unusual where I live.

In the U.S. most employment is on an "at will" basis. That means you can quit anytime you like without notice and you can be fired at any time for almost any reason or no reason, as long as the reason is not one of the protected reasons.

Comment: **Every** employee personally has an employment contract, whether it is individual or collective. It makes no sense to talk of someone who has a paid job without a contract, else what are they doing with their time and why is someone giving them money for it?

Comment: @Nij, in the US, formal written employment contracts are seldom used.  There is an implied contract of employment, but it would not be enough to enforce action on a company move.

Comment: An implied contract is a contract. Written documents of such have never been necessary to establish their existence nor for most of the general terms.

Comment: @nij I'm not sure what you're trying to get at with your comments. If there's no written contract, there's certainly nothing that would imply that the business would never relocate. And since NJ is an at will state, the op can be let go (or quit) if he decides he doesn't want to make the new commute.

Comment: Nothing in a written contract normally makes that guarantee either, and not having it written does not mean the employee hasn't got a contract. Your comment perpetuates myths about contract law and documentation, and doesn't even need to, because it focuses on an irrelevant aspect of any potential contract. It is the absence of a specific clause in the contract, not whether the contract is written down, that matters.